# How to use OAuth with Exchange Server

Tags: java, selenium, outlook, selenium-chromedriver

Actually in our automation we need to fetch email from outlook for which we created a function which uses exchange service using basic auth.

But due to some conditional access policy we are not able to use basic AUTH. Now we need to use modern AUTH to fetch the email data.

Can anyone help me to get the resources or some way to achieve this using modern auth.

Comment: What is the exact API you are using POP3? IMAP4? Are you asking how to use OAuth with Exchange server? Keep in mind that Outlook is a client app, you can't connect to it using POP3 or IMAP4.

Comment: Yeah it actually how to use OAuth with exchange server

Answer (score 0):

See [Authenticate an IMAP, POP or SMTP connection using OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth) on MSDN